# Expose New user meta to WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have registered a new meta key for users, and I need to expose it to the WooCommerce REST API. Whats the best way to do this? Im looking at `register_meta()` but not sure if thats the correct way to go for a user key.

I can see this key if I use the customer endpoint: /wp-json/wc/v3/customers/custome_number

but I want this exposed to the order endpoint: /wp-json/wc/v3/orders/order_number.

**Code:**

```
function add_to_group( $user_id ) {
$secret_string=wp_generate_password( 8, false );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'secret_key', $secret_string);
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'add_to_group' );
```

Comment: Can you please tell us which REST API endpoint you want to extend?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Updated the question with the endpoint, thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Jo I just realised I see the meta key if I use the customer endpoint: /wp-json/wc/v3/customers/91005412 . I just need this key to be exposed to the order endpoint as well.

Comment: I've actually had no time yet to get on my PC checking this - but why you don't use the customer from the order to request the customer in a second request? Would be cleaner as well!

Comment: @Mr.Jo Good point. Not sure if this is possible, there is a thir doarty requestion this key and Im not sure if their system can handle the second request, so would rather include it in the first order request.

Comment: Sure, this is possible! You can read the customer from an order and do a second request. I don't know where the problem should be? It's a simple request. If your system can't handle 2 requests, you should consider upgrading your system, since running WordPress on low resources is a bad idea when going big.

Comment: @Mr.Jo - Im talking about the third party and how they are calling it, they mainly operates with orders from us - they need this meta key together with order id and a few other variables for a specific link, and Im not sure their system is able to combine the two requests in the way they need it to operate. IfI can get the secret key meta in the order response this problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way. Maybe you need to adjust some things but it should work. Goes into your `functions.php` file of your child theme (or class):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object', 'filter_woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object', 10, 3 );
function filter_woocommerce_rest_prepare_shop_order_object( $response, $object, $request ) {
    if ( empty( $response ) || ! isset( $response->data['customer_id'] ) ) {
        return $response;
    }

    $customer_id = $response->data['customer_id'];

    if ( $customer_id === null ) { // Do not use empty() since there is a user with 0 as id (Admin) which will be skipped in this case
        return $response;
    }

    $secret_key = get_user_meta( absint( $customer_id ), 'secret_key', true );

    if ( ! empty( $secret_key ) ) {
        $response->data['customer_secret_key'] = $secret_key;
    }

    return $response;
}
```

You can see that the custom meta is in the response:

```
"date_created_gmt": "2021-07-16T08:37:48",
"date_modified_gmt": "2021-07-16T12:21:53",
"date_completed_gmt": null,
"date_paid_gmt": null,
"shipments": [],
"currency_symbol": "€",
"customer_secret_key": "123",
```

Comment: Thats works perfect - just what I was looking for. Interesting.

Comment: @Jerry Maybe you can give the answer a vote as well in case it helped you! :)